# Setting Category to off on a Card visual through Power BI embedded API

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-api

We would like to set **Category** to *off* on a `card` visual through the Power BI Embedded API. Is this possible?

I’ve tried setting the property `CategoryAxis`, `Visible` to `false`, but this did not achieve the desired outcome of suppressing the automatically generated title of the card.

In other words, the visual appears like this by default:

[image: Default Card Visual Rendering]

When you turn category off:

[image: Turning Category off]

You get this:

[image: Card Visual with category off]

We want to move the slider across programmatically using the API after the visual has been loaded, similar to changing title size for example, which can be done using `setProperty` as shown here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/visual-properties#available-properties-for-out-of-the-box-visuals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by applying a [theme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-report-themes).

The following theme json removes the category label on a card visual:

```js
const changeCardVisualTheme: Theme = {
      name: 'cardVisual',
      visualStyles: {
        card: {
          '*': {
            categoryLabels: [{
              show: false
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

Then to apply it using the Power Bi Report object in JavaScript:

```js
await report.applyTheme(changeCardVisualTheme)
```